# Printing an array of structs of structs results in an unexpected execution error?

Tags: c++, struct, malloc

For this struct definitions, I initialize all of them then print their contents with printstruct(); but after printing the first element the program hangs unexpectedly, 
1.I was thinking that if malloc() fails it would be for all elements right?.
2.I unfortunately have to work with thse structs, any ideas whats wrong with the code below?
**Note:**
All char arrays have their sizes equal to max length of the content they will receive plus one for null terminating character '\0', each team has 7 players maximum, amount of teams is 21000.
*Sorry for this kind of error-checking question but I have never worked with structs in C++ in the past.*

```
typedef struct Player{
char firstName[50];
char lastName[50];
}Player;

typedef struct Team{
    int id;
    char title[50];
    char summary[100];
    int numberOfPlayers;
    Player *players;
}Team;

typedef struct TeamsLog{
    Team *arr;
    int numberOfTeams;
}Teams;

int main()
{
   TeamsLog log;
   log.numberOfTeams = 21000;
   log.arr = (Team*)malloc(log.numberOfTeams * sizeof(Team));

    for (int i = 0; i < log.numberOfTeams; ++i)
    {
        (log.arr+ i)->id = 1;
        (log.arr + i)->numberOfPlayers = 7;
        for (int l = 0; l < 10; ++l)
        {
            (log.arr + i)->summary[l] = '0' + l;
            (log.arr + i)->title[l] = '0' + l;
        }
        (log.arr + i)->summary[10] = '\0';
        (log.arr + i)->title[10] = '\0';
        log.arr->players = (Player*)malloc(7 * sizeof(Player*));
        for (int l = 0; l < 7; ++l)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k){
                (log.arr + i)->players[l].firstName[k] = '0' + k;
                (log.arr + i)->players[l].lastName[k] = '0' + k;
            }
            (log.arr + i)->players[l].firstName[10] = '\0';
            (log.arr + i)->players[l].lastName[10] = '\0';
        }
        printstruct(log.arr + i);
     }


}
```

Code of printstruct():

```
void printstruct(Team* arg)
{
    cout << "\nTeam Name: " << arg->title
         << "\nId: " << arg->id
         << "\nSummary: " << arg->summary
         << "\nNumber of players: " << arg->numberOfPlayers << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < arg->numberOfPlayers; ++j)
        cout << "Player " << j+1 << " " << ((arg->players) + j)->firstName << " " 
             << ((arg->players) + j)->lastName << endl;
}
```

Comment: "All char arrays have their sizes equal to max length of the content they will receive"... + 1 for the terminating `\0`?

Comment: @Paul Roub Including '\0' I'll edit thanks for pointing it out

Comment: `sizeof(Player*)` should be `sizeof(Player)`. And use `std::string` and `std::vector` insead of this error-prone pointer juggling (or switch to C, if you like that kind of thing).

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks a lot, haven't noticed the extra *  and I assure you I use safe class containers  in my regular projects, but this one is just for education purposes.

Comment: Just an FYI: `(log.arr + i)->` can be more succinctly expressed as `log.arr[i].`

Comment: @EdS. Thanks a million, I haven't thought the equivalence.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I disagree.  How is a beginner supposed to appreciate the benefits of e.g. RAII if they don't first understand the pitfalls of manual memory management?  Understanding the computer/OS at a deeper level is only going to help.

Comment: @EdS. I seriously disagree with you too. _"How is a beginner supposed ..."_ using manually managed memory _isn't for beginners_, but ***advanced usage***. That's one of the point's most of the profs seem to fail, when teaching c++ (data structures).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Well, I suppose we'll just have to agree to disagree then.  More and more programmers are coming up who have no idea how any of the code they write actually works. To me, that's a bit scary.  On average, they don't seem to go back and learn this stuff.

Comment: @Ed S.: so you would encourage beginners to first learn assembler, so they can 'appreciate' the "beauty" of c++? Sorry, but I'd rather do the exact opposite: First teach them to use vectors, strings, smart pointers etc. And only when they are used to this, show them that there are more low level constructs which they might need in some special cases.

Comment: @EdS.Hmm, operating within the standard [Dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) and [Containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) libraries, there's narrow chances that `new` or `delete` need to be used explicitly. The code written using these classes and idions, should just work, without having to bother with any memory management related problems.

Comment: @EdS. I'm an evangelist of this opiniion: http://dev-jungle.blogspot.de/2015/02/i-have-dream-im-dreaming-of-so-called-c.html

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ
I know it  sounds contradictory but I agree with both of you,
A student should have insight of lower levels of programming but certainly should not be forced to use them in a big project while there are optimized safe containers and smarter memory management build in any language

Comment: @wing There's nothing wrong with studying about low level memory management. My only point is it's not a thing that beginners should be taught in 1st place. It's _advanced usage_, and thus the standard features were introduced (incrementally). Even for pre-c++11  standards, there was `std::auto_ptr<>` to get ownership of dynamically allocated pointers right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copy/pasted your code I got a segfault because of the following:

```
 log.arr->players = (Player*)malloc(7 * sizeof(Player*));
```

You forgot add the index so it is trying to malloc memory in the same spot every  time you go through the loop, causing a segfault. Also as mentioned in the comments, you should be using sizeof(Player) instead of sizeof(Player*).

Following your style, it should be:

```
 (log.arr + i)->players = (Player*)malloc(7 * sizeof(Player));
```

I would suggest making Team *arr a std::vector and Player *players a std::vector (assuming you want a dynamic container). Vector will take care of the memory management (through its Allocator) and will improve the code's readability and make it easier to use in the future (code reuse).

Comment: I tested the Code, I read 21000 records perfectly , you are absolutely correct. Thank you so much, I have been troubled by this code for 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using **C++** I would like to make you recommendations, what I'm about to write is too long for doit into a comment, hence was wrote as answer.

**Use smart pointers.**

With smart pointer you don't have (generaly) to care about memory management.

Links fo Interest:

[Smart Pointers (Modern C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx), [Smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)

**Use [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) always you can.**

You're coding using C++ language, way don't use it? Are you bind to use `char`?

**The same program (in C++):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef struct Player{
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
}Player;

typedef struct Team{
    int id;
    std::string title;
    std::string summary;
    int numberOfPlayers;
    std::vector<Player> players;
}Team;

typedef struct TeamsLog{
    std::vector<Team> arr;
    int numberOfTeams;
}Teams;


void printstruct(const Team& team)
{
    std::cout << "\nTeam Name: " << team.title
        << "\nId: " << team.id
        << "\nSummary: " << team.summary
        << "\nNumber of players: " << team.numberOfPlayers << std::endl;


    int index = 0;
    for (auto &player : team.players)
    {
        std::cout << "Player " << ++index << " " << player.firstName << " " << player.lastName << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    TeamsLog log;
    log.numberOfTeams = 21000;
    log.arr.reserve(21000);  // This is not really needed but improve performance.

    for (int i = 0; i < log.numberOfTeams; ++i)
    {
        Team team;
        team.id = 1;
        team.numberOfPlayers = 7;

        team.summary = "some summary";
        team.title = "some title";

        team.players.reserve(7);

        for (int l = 0; l < 7; ++l)
        {
            Player player;
            player.firstName = "Some name";
            player.lastName = "Some last name";
            team.players.push_back(player);
        }
        log.arr.push_back(team);
        printstruct(log.arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually use a mix of both char and std::string
Because I am forced to base my c++ project on those C-style Structs
By the way thanks you for the links, 
I didn't know the concept of smart pointer until today